# LF: flexible scheduler/timer library

Tags: library, timers

I'm working on a few arduino projects where I've needed a flexible scheduler and/or timer library and was wondering if anyone has a library they recommend?

**Case 1:**
I have a sensor that needs to collect observations every hour, but it has a specific  measurement sequence:

- Power up/boot (takes about 15 seconds)
- Warm-up for 60 seconds.
- Observe (2 min), collect raw data, generate stats
- Cool-down for 5 min.
- Power off

In this case have a single micro-controller acting as a data-logger that is controlling multiple sensors and writing to an SD card.

**Case 2:**
I have an oven that needs to be controlled to a user-specified temperature profile (up say to 6 points of change), i.e.:

- Turn on heater
- Set temperature, 100C and hold for 2 min
- Set temperature, 160C and hold for 15 min
- Set temperature, 250C and hold for 1 hr
- ....
- Set temperature, 100C and hold for 1 hr
- Turn off heater

I'm familiar with non-blocking timers and (in the past) have cobbled together a few simple timers with millis() and some ulong variables. Alas, the complexity and debugging time rapidly grows with the number of dependent timers. Before I sit down and sketch out a class definition, I figured I'd ask what others are using.

Comment: You could use a RTC for more accurate timing.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Arduion_FreeRTOS](https://github.com/feilipu/Arduino_FreeRTOS_Library) which implement an FreeRTOS kernel under the Arduino environement.

Answer (score 1):

Some libraries I find good (opinion-based):

- TaskManagerIO: https://github.com/davetcc/TaskManagerIO

  - does a good job at managing events / scheduling things for a certain (system) time, or even repetitively.
  - with that you could e.g. use a `scheduleFixedRate()` API to call a function every 60 minutes. Then starts the power up (I assume asynchronously, by setting a pin or something), and just primes the scheduler with the `scheduleOnce()` API to call another function in 15 seconds. That target function then starts the warmup and schedules the next function / step for 60 seconds into the future, et cetera. It would express the flow very naturally.
- If accurate timekeeping is needed so that it's really every hour, you might want to  use an external RTC module. Also depends on the microcontroller you're using, many have a builtin one that you can feed with a 32.768 kHz crystal and thus you don't need an external chip

  - library for the DS3231 / DS3232 RTC lets you set an alarm in the RTC: https://github.com/JChristensen/DS3232RTC/blob/master/alarm-primer.md
  - with that you can e.g. set an alarm for every 60 minutes and then execute your task.